# Deleting iPlanetDirectoryPro cookie

Tags: java, session, openam

I am trying to delete iPlanetDirectoryPro cookie in logout using following code.

```
       cookie.setMaxAge(0);
       cookie.setValue("");
       response.addCookie(cookie);
```

But still it is not getting deleted.
What are other options to delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the same cookie domain for clearing the cookie, as what was used to create the cookie (and have the same path potentially).

Comment: By adding setDomain and setPath, I was able to delete it.
Thanks.